# SQL Server Reporting Services: How to check who accessed certain report?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, ssrs, access-control

I am in process of eliminating who should have access to SQL Server Reporting Services reports that I have created.  Is there a way to find out who has accessed certain reports during past month?

My goal here is to remove people who hasn't accessed the report for awhile.

Answer (score 1):

Suggest you not to remove people but disable their login or just revoke access.

Then after a full business cycle, if no one complains then remove those users.

> Is there a way to find out who has accessed certain reports during past month?

Below is the query that will give the report you need. There are more report queries available at [this link](http://blogs.wrox.com/article/creating-a-report-server-usage-report-with-sql-server-reporting-services/) :

**Note:** Adjust the query as per your need.

```
 – Execution Log:



– For debugging (remove next 4 lines after pasting to dataset) –

DECLARE @DateFrom Date

DECLARE @DateTo Date

SET @DateFrom = ’2008-01-01′

SET @DateTo = ’2008-06-30′

– End debugging script –



SELECT    

      DATEPART(Hour, TimeStart) AS ReportYear

    , DATEPART(Month, TimeStart) AS ReportMonth

    , DATEPART(Day, TimeStart) AS ReportDay

    , DATEPART(Hour, TimeStart) AS ReportHour

    , Type

    , COUNT(Name) AS ExecutionCount

    , SUM(TimeDataRetrieval) AS TimeDataRetrievalSum

    , SUM(TimeProcessing) AS TimeProcessingSum

    , SUM(TimeRendering) AS TimeRenderingSum

    , SUM(ByteCount) AS ByteCountSum

    , SUM([RowCount]) AS RowCountSum

FROM

(

    SELECT TimeStart, Catalog.Type, Catalog.Name, TimeDataRetrieval,

  TimeProcessing, TimeRendering, ByteCount, [RowCount]

    FROM

    Catalog INNER JOIN ExecutionLog ON Catalog.ItemID =

       ExecutionLog.ReportID LEFT OUTER JOIN

    Users ON Catalog.CreatedByID = Users.UserID

    WHERE ExecutionLog.TimeStart BETWEEN @DateFrom AND @DateTo

) AS RE

GROUP BY

      DATEPART(Hour, TimeStart)

    , DATEPART(Month, TimeStart)

    , DATEPART(Day, TimeStart)

    , DATEPART(Hour, TimeStart)

    , Type

ORDER BY

      ReportYear

    , ReportMonth

    , ReportDay

    , ReportHour

    , Type
```